# general operator for function

Tags: haskell, operators

Suppose I have a function like:

```hs
kua 0 a b = a * b
kua n a b = foldr (kua $ n-1) 1 [a | _ <- [1..b]]
```

(kua = [Knuth's up arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation))

If I were to bind the function to an operator based on the number of 'up-arrows' `n`,

```hs
(|>) = kua 1
(|>>) = kua 2
(|>>>) = kua 3
```

would there be a way of generalizing the operator based on `n`?

I am aware, that I could just call `kua n`, but I am interested if this could be expressed with a single operator for every case.

Comment: No. There is no provision for inferring data from the lexical structure of an operator. That's why you see a large, but fixed, number of instances for various tuple types like `(,)`, `(,,)`, etc.

Comment: (At least, not without using Template Haskell. I don't know anything about how to use it, but once you get to the level of effectively writing code on the fly, just about anything is possible.)

Comment: (It's not like you'll be able to actually *run* most code involving values of `n` larger than 3 in a reasonable amount of time, anyway, so it's kind of a moot point.)

Comment: This could turn into my favourite new toy. tysm @chepner
Also, this is why I chose Knuth in the first place, it just adds to the redundancy :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please never actually do something like this, it's horrible.

But, here goes...

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell     #-}

module KnuthArrows where

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

kua :: Int -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
kua 0 a b = a * b
kua n a b = foldl' (flip . kua $ n-1) 1 [a | _ <- [1..b]]

knuthArrows :: Int -> DecsQ
knuthArrows lim = concat <$> forM [1..lim] `id` \n -> do
   let arrowOp = mkName $ replicate n '↑'
       fixity = InfixD (Fixity 8 InfixN) arrowOp
   signature <- SigD arrowOp <$> [t| Integer -> Integer -> Integer |]
   definition <- [d| $(varP arrowOp) = kua n |]
   return $ fixity : signature : definition
```

To be used like (*this must be in a separate module*)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell     #-}

import KnuthArrows

knuthArrows 10
```

to get

```
*Main> :browse
(↑) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(↑↑) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(↑↑↑) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(↑↑↑↑) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(↑↑↑↑↑) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(↑↑↑↑↑↑) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(↑↑↑↑↑↑↑) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
(↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
*Main> 2↑↑3
16
*Main> 2↑↑↑3
65536
*Main> 2↑↑5
2003529930406846464979072351560255750447825475569751419265016973710894059556311453089506130880933348101038234342907263181822949382118812668869506364761547029165041871916351587966347219442930927982084309104855990570159318959639524863372367203002916969592156108764948889254090805911457037675208500206671563702366126359747144807111774815880914135742720967190151836282560618091458852699826141425030123391108273603843767876449043205960379124490905707560314035076162562476031863793126484703743782954975613770981604614413308692118102485959152380195331030292162800160568670105651646750568038741529463842244845292537361442533614373729088303794601274724958414864915930647252015155693922628180691650796381064132275307267143998158508811292628901134237782705567421080070065283963322155077831214288551675554073345107213112427399562982719769150054883905223804357045848197956393157853510018992000024141963706813559840464039472194016069517690156119726982337890017641517190051133466306898140219383481435426387306539552969691388024158161859561100640362119796101859534802787167200122604642492385111393400464351623867567078745259464670903886547743483217897012764455529409092021959585751622973333576159552394885297579954028471943529913543763705986928913757153740001986394332464890052543106629669165243419174691389632476560289415199775477703138064781342309596190960654591300890188887588084733625956065444888501447335706058817090162108499714529568344061979690565469813631162053579369791403236328496233046421066136200220175787851857409162050489711781820400187282939943446186224328009837323764931814789848119452713007440220765680910376203999203492023906626264491909167985461515778839060397720759279378852241294301017458086862263369284725851403039615558564330385450688652213114813638408384778263790459607186876728509763471271988890680478243230394718650525660978150729861141430305816927924971409161059417185352275887504477592218301158780701975535722241400019548102005661773589781499532325208589753463547007786690406429016763808161740550405117670093673202804549339027992491867306539931640720492238474815280619166900933805732120816350707634351669869625020969023162859350071874190579161241536897514808261904847946571736601005892476655445840838334790544144817684255327207315586349347605137419779525190365032198020108764738368682531025183377533908861426184800374008082238104076468878471647552945326947661700424461063311238021134588694532200116564076327023074292426051582811070387018345324567635625951430032037432740780879056283663406965030844225855967039271869461158513793386475699748568670079823960604393478850861649260304945061743412365828352144806726676841807083754862211408236579802961200027441324438432402331257403545019352428776430880232850855886089962774458164680857875115807014743763867976955049991643998284357290415378143438847303484261903388841494031366139854257635577105335580206622185577060082551288893332226436281984838613239570676191409638533832374343758830859233722284644287996245605476932428998432652677378373173288063210753211238680604674708428051166488709084770291208161104912555598322366244868556651402684641209694982590565519216188104341226838996283071654868525536914850299539675503954938371853405900096187489473992880432496373165753803673586710175783994818471798498246948060532081996066183434012476096639519778021441199752546704080608499344178256285092726523709898651539462193004607364507926212975917698293892367015170992091531567814439791248475706237804600009918293321306880570046591458387208088016887445835557926258465124763087148566313528934166117490617526671492672176128330845273936469244582892571388877839056300482483799839692029222215486145902373478222682521639957440801727144146179559226175083889020074169926238300282286249284182671243405751424188569994272331606998712986882771820617214453142574944015066139463169197629181506579745526236191224848063890033669074365989226349564114665503062965960199720636202603521917776740668777463549375318899587866282125469797102065747232721372918144666659421872003474508942830911535189271114287108376159222380276605327823351661555149369375778466670145717971901227117812780450240026384758788339396817962950690798817121690686929538248529830023476068454114178139110648560236549754227497231007615131870024053910510913817843721791422528587432098524957878034683703337818421444017138688124249984418618129271198533315382567321870421530631197748535214670955334626336610864667332292409879849256691109516143618601548909740241913509623043612196128165950518666022030715613684732364660868905014263913906515063908199378852318365059897299125404479443425166774299659811849233151555272883274028352688442408752811283289980625912673699546247341543333500147231430612750390307397135252069338173843322950701049061867539433130784798015655130384758155685236218010419650255596181934986315913233036096461905990236112681196023441843363334594927631946101716652913823717182394299216272538461776065694542297877071383198817036964588689811863210976900355735884624464835706291453052757101278872027965364479724025405448132748391794128826423835171949197209797145936887537198729130831738033911016128547415377377715951728084111627597186384924222802373441925469991983672192131287035585307966942713416391033882754318613643490100943197409047331014476299861725424423355612237435715825933382804986243892498222780715951762757847109475119033482241412025182688713728193104253478196128440176479531505057110722974314569915223451643121848657575786528197564843508958384722923534559464521215831657751471298708225909292655638836651120681943836904116252668710044560243704200663709001941185557160472044643696932850060046928140507119069261393993902735534545567470314903886022024639948260501762431969305640666366626090207048887438898907498152865444381862917382901051820869936382661868303915273264581286782806601337500096593364625146091723180312930347877421234679118454791311109897794648216922505629399956793483801699157439700537542134485874586856047286751065423341893839099110586465595113646061055156838541217459801807133163612573079611168343863767667307354583494789788316330129240800836356825939157113130978030516441716682518346573675934198084958947940983292500086389778563494693212473426103062713745077286156922596628573857905533240641849018451328284632709269753830867308409142247659474439973348130810986399417379789657010687026734161967196591599588537834822988270125605842365589539690306474965584147981310997157542043256395776070485100881578291408250777738559790129129407309462785944505859412273194812753225152324801503466519048228961406646890305102510916237770448486230229488966711380555607956620732449373374027836767300203011615227008921843515652121379215748206859356920790214502277133099987729459596952817044582181956080965811702798062669891205061560742325686842271306295009864421853470810407128917646906550836129916694778023822502789667843489199409657361704586786242554006942516693979292624714524945408858422726153755260071904336329196375777502176005195800693847635789586878489536872122898557806826518192703632099480155874455575175312736471421295536494084385586615208012115079075068553344489258693283859653013272046970694571546959353658571788894862333292465202735853188533370948455403336565356988172582528918056635488363743793348411845580168331827676834646291995605513470039147876808640322629616641560667508153710646723108461964247537490553744805318226002710216400980584497526023035640038083472053149941172965736785066421400842696497103241919182121213206939769143923368374709228267738708132236680086924703491586840991153098315412063566123187504305467536983230827966457417620806593177265685841681837966106144963432544111706941700222657817358351259821080769101961052229263879745049019254311900620561906577452416191913187533984049343976823310298465893318373015809592522829206820862230332585280119266496314441316442773003237792274712330696417149945532261035475145631290668854345426869788447742981777493710117614651624183616680254815296335308490849943006763654806102940094693750609845588558043970485914449584445079978497045583550685408745163316464118083123079704389849190506587586425810738422420591191941674182490452700288263983057950057341711487031187142834184499153456702915280104485145176055306971441761368582384102787659324662689978418319620312262421177391477208004883578333569204533935953254564897028558589735505751235129536540502842081022785248776603574246366673148680279486052445782673626230852978265057114624846595914210278122788941448163994973881884622768244851622051817076722169863265701654316919742651230041757329904473537672536845792754365412826553581858046840069367718605020070547247548400805530424951854495267247261347318174742180078574693465447136036975884118029408039616746946288540679172138601225419503819704538417268006398820656328792839582708510919958839448297775647152026132871089526163417707151642899487953564854553553148754978134009964854498635824847690590033116961303766127923464323129706628411307427046202032013368350385425360313636763575212604707425311209233402837482949453104727418969287275572027615272268283376741393425652653283068469997597097750005560889932685025049212884068274139881631540456490350775871680074055685724021758685439053228133770707415830756269628316955687424060527726485853050611356384851965918968649596335568216975437621430778665934730450164822432964891270709898076676625671517269062058815549666382573829274182082278960684488222983394816670984039024283514306813767253460126007269262969468672750794346190439996618979611928750519442356402644303271737341591281496056168353988188569484045342311424613559925272330064881627466723523751234311893442118885085079358163848994487544756331689213869675574302737953785262542329024881047181939037220666894702204258836895840939998453560948869946833852579675161882159410981624918741813364726965123980677561947912557957446471427868624053750576104204267149366084980238274680575982591331006919941904651906531171908926077949119217946407355129633864523035673345588033313197080365457184791550432654899559705862888286866606618021882248602144999973122164138170653480175510438406624412822803616648904257377640956326482825258407669045608439490325290526337532316509087681336614242398309530806549661879381949120033919489494065132398816642080088395554942237096734840072642705701165089075196155370186264797456381187856175457113400473810762763014953309735174180655479112660938034311378532532883533352024934365979129341284854970946826329075830193072665337782559314331110963848053940859283988907796210479847919686876539987477095912788727475874439806779824968278272200926449944559380414608770641941810440758269805688038949654616587983904660587645341810289907194293021774519976104495043196841503455514044820928933378657363052830619990077748726922998608279053171691876578860908941817057993404890218441559791092676862796597583952483926734883634745651687016166240642424241228961118010615682342539392180052483454723779219911228595914191877491793823340010078128326506710281781396029120914720100947878752551263372884222353869490067927664511634758101193875319657242121476038284774774571704578610417385747911301908583877890152334343013005282797038580359815182929600305682612091950943737325454171056383887047528950563961029843641360935641632589408137981511693338619797339821670761004607980096016024823096943043806956620123213650140549586250615282588033022908385812478469315720323233601899469437647726721879376826431828382603564520699468630216048874528424363593558622333506235945002890558581611275341783750455936126130852640828051213873177490200249552738734585956405160830583053770732533971552620444705429573538361113677523169972740292941674204423248113875075631319078272188864053374694213842169928862940479635305150560788126366206497231257579019598873041195626227343728900516561111094111745277965482790471250581999077498063821559376885546498822938985408291325129076478386322494781016753491693489288104203015610283386143827378160946341335383578340765314321417150655877547820252454780657301342277470616744241968952613164274104695474621483756288299771804186785084546965619150908695874251184435837306590951460980451247409411373899927822492983367796011015387096129749705566301637307202750734759922943792393824427421186158236161317886392553095117188421298508307238259729144142251579403883011359083331651858234967221259621812507058113759495525022747274674369887131926670769299199084467161228738858457584622726573330753735572823951616964175198675012681745429323738294143824814377139861906716657572945807804820559511881687188075212971832636442155336787751274766940790117057509819575084563565217389544179875074523854455200133572033332379895074393905312918212255259833790909463630202185353848854825062897715616963860712382771725621313460549401770413581731931763370136332252819127547191443450920711848838366818174263342949611870091503049165339464763717766439120798347494627397822171502090670190302469762151278521956142070806461631373236517853976292092025500288962012970141379640038055734949269073535145961208674796547733692958773628635660143767964038430796864138563447801328261284589184898528048048844180821639423974014362903481665458114454366460032490618763039502356402044530748210241366895196644221339200757479128683805175150634662569391937740283512075666260829890491877287833852178522792045771846965855278790447562192663992008409302075673925363735628390829817577902153202106409617373283598494066652141198183810884515459772895164572131897797907491941013148368544639616904607030107596818933741217575988165127000761262789169510406315857637534787420070222051070891257612361658026806815858499852631465878086616800733264676830206391697203064894405628195406190685242003053463156621891327309069687353181641094514288036605995220248248886711554429104721929134248346438705368508648749099178812670565665387191049721820042371492740164460943459845392536706132210616533085662021188968234005752675486101476993688738209584552211571923479686888160853631615862880150395949418529489227074410828207169303387818084936204018255222271010985653444817207470756019245915599431072949578197878590578940052540122867517142511184356437184053563024181225473266093302710397968091064939272722683035410467632591355279683837705019855234621222858410557119921731717969804339317707750755627056047831779844447637560254637033369247114220815519973691371975163241302748712199863404548248524570118553342675264715978310731245663429805221455494156252724028915333354349341217862037007260315279870771872491234494477147909520734761385425485311552773301030342476835865496093722324007154518129732692081058424090557725645803681462234493189708138897143299831347617799679712453782310703739151473878692119187566700319321281896803322696594459286210607438827416919465162267632540665070881071030394178860564893769816734159025925194611823642945652669372203155504700213598846292758012527715422016629954863130324912311029627923723899766416803497141226527931907636326136814145516376656559839788489381733082668779901962886932296597379951931621187215455287394170243669885593888793316744533363119541518404088283815193421234122820030950313341050704760159987985472529190665222479319715440331794836837373220821885773341623856441380700541913530245943913502554531886454796252260251762928374330465102361057583514550739443339610216229675461415781127197001738611494279501411253280621254775810512972088465263158094806633687670147310733540717710876615935856814098212967730759197382973441445256688770855324570888958320993823432102718224114763732791357568615421252849657903335093152776925505845644010552192644505312073756287744998163646332835816140330175813967359427327690448920361880386754955751806890058532927201493923500525845146706982628548257883267398735220457228239290207144822219885587102896991935873074277815159757620764023951243860202032596596250212578349957710085626386118233813318509014686577064010676278617583772772895892746039403930337271873850536912957126715066896688493880885142943609962012966759079225082275313812849851526902931700263136328942095797577959327635531162066753488651317323872438748063513314512644889967589828812925480076425186586490241111127301357197181381602583178506932244007998656635371544088454866393181708395735780799059730839094881804060935959190907473960904410150516321749681412100765719177483767355751000733616922386537429079457803200042337452807566153042929014495780629634138383551783599764708851349004856973697965238695845994595592090709058956891451141412684505462117945026611750166928260250950770778211950432617383223562437601776799362796099368975191394965033358507155418436456852616674243688920371037495328425927131610537834980740739158633817967658425258036737206469351248652238481341663808061505704829059890696451936440018597120425723007316410009916987524260377362177763430621616744884930810929901009517974541564251204822086714586849255132444266777127863728211331536224301091824391243380214046242223349153559516890816288487989988273630445372432174280215755777967021666317047969728172483392841015642274507271779269399929740308072770395013581545142494049026536105825409373114653104943382484379718606937214444600826798002471229489405761853892203425608302697052876621377373594394224114707074072902725461307358541745691419446487624357682397065703184168467540733466346293673983620004041400714054277632480132742202685393698869787607009590048684650626771363070979821006557285101306601010780633743344773073478653881742681230743766066643312775356466578603715192922768440458273283243808212841218776132042460464900801054731426749260826922155637405486241717031027919996942645620955619816454547662045022411449404749349832206807191352767986747813458203859570413466177937228534940031631599544093684089572533438702986717829770373332806801764639502090023941931499115009105276821119510999063166150311585582835582607179410052528583611369961303442790173811787412061288182062023263849861515656451230047792967563618345768105043341769543067538041113928553792529241347339481050532025708728186307291158911335942014761872664291564036371927602306283840650425441742335464549987055318726887926424102147363698625463747159744354943443899730051742525110877357886390946812096673428152585919924857640488055071329814299359911463239919113959926752576359007446572810191805841807342227734721397723218231771716916400108826112549093361186780575722391018186168549108500885272274374212086524852372456248697662245384819298671129452945515497030585919307198497105414181636968976131126744027009648667545934567059936995464500558921628047976365686133316563907395703272034389175415267500915011198856872708848195531676931681272892143031376818016445477367518353497857924276463354162433601125960252109501612264110346083465648235597934274056868849224458745493776752120324703803035491157544831295275891939893680876327685438769557694881422844311998595700727521393176837831770339130423060958999137314684569010422095161967070506420256733873446115655276175992727151877660010238944760539789516945708802728736225121076224091810066700883474737605156285533943565843756271241244457651663064085939507947550920463932245202535463634444791755661725962187199279186575490857852950012840229035061514937310107009446151011613712423761426722541732055959202782129325725947146417224977321316381845326555279604270541871496236585252458648933254145062642337885651464670604298564781968461593663288954299780722542264790400616019751975007460545150060291806638271497016110987951336633771378434416194053121445291855180136575558667615019373029691932076120009255065081583275508499340768797252369987023567931026804136745718956641431852679054717169962990363015545645090044802789055701968328313630718997699153166679208958768572290600915472919636381673596673959975710326015571920237348580521128117458610065152598883843114511894880552129145775699146577530041384717124577965048175856395072895337539755822087777506072339445587895905719156736
```